# How to restrict users to open account page before login?

Tags: html

I am working on HTML for a couple of months. I have developed a login.html page with form input of username and password. And another accounts.html page to show account info after correct login. But users can directly open accounts.html by typing on the url bar like: https://www.example.com/acounts.html without logging in. My question is how to not let users do this thing without login?

update: it can be done through cookies and i did it!

Comment: you can't do that with "just" html. you need a server and a database in the background. take a look at this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xb8aad4MRx8

Comment: If you do not realise that this is not possible with HTML, then I advise you to stick with front-end for a while. First get better with HTML, CSS, and JS. Then jump to others such as PHP, or new frameworks completely.

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain a session when user login, and you have to redirect user on login page only until they don't login successfully.

Comment: But how to maintain a session variable. Could you explain,please?

Answer (score 0):

You should be saving this information inside LocalStorage, SesisonStorage or Cookies with Javascript, isn't it?

Something like:

```
localStorage.setItem("userName", "John");
```

A verification is, when account.js is loaded, check if this is null

```
if(localStorage.getItem("userName") == null) {
     window.location.replace("http://example.com/login.html");
}
```

Comment: I downvoted because if a user has disabled JavaScript they can still easily access the accounts page.

Comment: Of course this validation should be done on server side, but the question starts with "I am working on HTML for a couple of months". The use of roles and authorities is a real solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, you can use [PHP](http://www.php.net/") and [Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php").

You will need a server to serve your pages I recommend [XAMPP which has apache server](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html).

There are many tutorials out there to help you with this and get your started but trying to explain how to do it all here is not exactly feasible.